# How do I capture audio from interactive webpages using VLC?

Tags: audio, vlc, screencasting

### I'm trying to capture an audio video feed (screen-cast) from my web browser and all screen-casting options I tried have the same issue:

## No sound is captured

---

#### Platform

I'm using a near default install of Linx Mint KDE x64 Petra.  The FLAC package is installed

Outputs of `cat /proc/asound/pcm`

```
00-00: ALC270 Analog : ALC270 Analog : playback 1 : capture 1 
00-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
```

---

#### My current process is

- open vlc and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
- change `Capture mode` to `Desktop`
- Change `Desired fame rate` to something reasonable (24 f/s)
- Check `Show more optoions`
- Change `Caching` to 0
- check `Play another media synchronously`

### I think the problem is in this next step:

- In the `Extra media` field I've tried entering `alsa://plughw` or `alsa://hw:0,0` as specified [here](https://nowardev.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/vlc-webcam-recording-destkop-screencast/).
- I've also tried browsing for my audio device:

  - I clicked `Capture Device` tab
  - Next to `Capture mode` I selected `Video for Linux 2`
  - Next to `Audio device name` I chose hw;0,0
  - I then pressed select

  **However, when I'm retured to the `Open Media` window, the text next to `Extra media` is filled in with `v4l2://` with no references to the audio device.**

Following this, I click the drop down next to `play` and choose convert and set the profile to `Video - Theora + Flac (OGG)` and set my destination file to `<someFile>.ogg` and hit `start` and launch the webpage I want to record.   The video comes out fine, but there is no audio.

<sub>**Note:**
As VLC's user-base is likely much larger than any other option I've tried, I've decided to restrict my focus to solving this issue for VLC but am not opposed to other solutions aside from the obvious bridging of the headphone and mic jacks via an 3.5mm audio cable.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

you can read the solution [here](http://nowardev.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/grab-desktop-with-audio-from-jack-with-vlc/) and [here](http://nowardev.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/flash-pulseaudio-jack-kde-linux-kubuntu/)  with more details, BTW to record a good audio you NEED to use jack to link the browser's audio output  to vlc

so shortly here :

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-jack qjackctl
```

now you nee d to run qjackctl and set like in this picture 
[image]

after that you can test here with this : in this case I have used mp3 and x264 like codecs you can just try to change that if you need.
File will be recorded in tmp folder and to stop recording just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

```
cd /tmp ; cvlc --jack-input-auto-connect screen:// --screen-fps=25 --input-slave pulse://jack_in --sout "#transcode{venc=x264,quality:50,scale=1,fps=25,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2, samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=nowardev.mp4}}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is much easier to watch at the websites source code (I think it was Ctrl+u in Firefox, if not just right click and »show source«) and search for the media being played. Then copy the media url and use `mplayer` to save the stream:

```
mplayer -dumpstream http://domainname.xyz/folder/containing/video.mp4
```

(could also be `flv` extension if it is a flash player based video stream, or webm or ogg or whatever).

To find the media url you could also use right click and »inspect element« and then click on the video. To achieve this, you have to click on the »select element with mouse« button (which is the leftmost button in the second row of the element inspector, in the image below the blue icon).

[image: Inspector]
<sub>(source: [mozillademos.org](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5323/inspector-no-element-selected.png))</sub>

Image source: https://superuser.com/questions/650434/firefox-dom-inspector-highlight-element-like-chrome-firebug

Comment: The problem is the site I'm trying to record is interactive, and thus there is no video filet to directly rip.